# ScalaTest Run Configuration in Eclipse: cannot find Suite Class

Tags: eclipse, scalatest

Problem: I cannot setup Run Configurations to run scalatest for the Scalatests in my project.

Steps to reproduce:

- Right click on Scala Suite and click on Run as -> Run configurations..
- On the left, I see a configuration template for ScalaTest. I click on New and fill the Name **but it cannot find the suite-class.**

Note: It is mentioned [here](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_eclipse) that I should see Run as -> ScalaTest - Suite but I do not see that option. I tried using context menu in the editor, and in the package explorer

Steps taken:

- Using: Scala IDE for Eclipse version: 2.1.0.m3-2_09
- Using SBT, assemble project, run eclipse command and then import project and dependencies into Eclipse
- Project compiles. ScalaTest code compiles(scalatest_2.9.2-1.8.jar is in the 'Referenced Libraries' configuration)

Comment: Just a quick thought... do you maybe have an `object` defined but the runner needs a `class`?

Comment: @asflierl: Nope,it is a class extending FunSuite

Comment: OK :-/  one more idea: is your test class in the default package? I can reproduce your case when I remove the package declaration from the top of a test class source file.

Comment: :(. No, the test class has a package declaration. package spark.bagel. Thanks for taking the time to help me :).

Comment: Another [possible solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25634638/759923) to this problem comes from @krzysiek-novak, in which he suggests adding a Run Configuration for the project, with type "Suite", and specifying "package.*" as the suite class, where package is a top level package from which you wish the discovery of tests to start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been fighting a similar problem for the past few days; Lily / Jimbo's answer didn't quite match my situation, but helped me find the right direction.

In my case, I was using a third-party library that I'd copied in. The package names of the classes and tests matched, but the folder structure did *not* -- all of my tests were directly in Play's "/test" folder, rather than in folders that matched the package names. This didn't show any errors, but was broken: packages ought to match folders. When I built the right folder structure underneath test, and recompiled, the expected "Run As -> ScalaTest - Suite" options showed up.

Don't know if your problem is the same, but you might check this if you haven't already found the issue...

Comment: For me it was a bit the other way around: I had the intended folder/package structure but the source files where missing the package declaration. Fixed it and indeed the menu items showed up.

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by a misalignment between the scalatest and the scala eclipse IDE version.  Try scalatest_2.9.0-2.0.M5b.jar  or scalatest_2.10-2.0.M5b.jar.  The former jar definitely works with ide 2.0.9.x  so maybe the new version needs the 2.10 jar.  Pick your version carefully from [here](http://www.scalatest.org/download)

Answer (score 1):

Willem's answer is what worked for me. Getting both plugins from the same update site (from the list on [Scalatest's github site](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest-eclipse-plugin)), seemed to work for me using Kepler.

Answer (score 1):

for my case, one click on 'Reimport All Maven Projects' icon, like 'Refresh' icon, solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you fixed the error, but I had similar a error yesterday and was pulling my hair trying to fix it (none of the suggestions I found by googling seemed to help me). So for me, it turns out that it's as easy as package hierarchy in my test suite.

I am using the play framework, so naturally my folders look like this `controllers.package1.package2....` and this applies to my test folders also.

Now my test classes however, have the package definition `package1.package2.....` (no "controllers" as prefix).

If I run the tests on sbt/play command prompt, it's not a problem. But running them through Eclipse would give me the problem you described.

So anyways... thought I'd share this, in case this could help.

Comment: I just downloaded scala-eclipse from typesafe :(. thanks though

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit annoying combined with the `view template` compile issue in play framework. but my approach is to regenerate the eclipse project file and add `view template` path into the **class path**